# How to properly do file caching in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

My server configuration has following lines:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 3d;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

The main problem is that for example when there is and url like `site.com/tags/node.js` NGINX throws 404 as `node.js` doesn't exists.

Is it possible somehow to check if file really exists and if not try it via `PHP`?

Comment: Please show the complete `server` block.

Comment: Seems like you need a basics tutorial. I wrote one for Nginx, Wordpress, and AWS that will teach you some. You're looking for try_files. https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/

Comment: The configuration needs something similar to a `try_files $uri /index.php;` directive on the second location block (that matches css and js files)